# How to train OpenNLP model to extract multi set words

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, opennlp, named-entity-recognition

I am newbie to Open NLP - Entity extraction with NER, I had train and evaluated models for Entity extraction in Open NLP NER, which works fine when I give input text with an entity of one word Eg: "I want to buy Cadbury"

But It does not works works for the Multi-word scenarios Eg: "I want to but an Apple MacBook"

How train the models to pick the multi word

PS: I have understood that I need to do something related with BiGrams provided in NLP, but how do i do it with OpenNLP?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide training data which covers multi-word spans. Example from the [OpenNLP documentation](https://opennlp.apache.org/docs/1.7.2/manual/opennlp.html#tools.namefind.recognition):

Besides the above format, [IO/BIO/etc tags](https://web.archive.org/web/20170805150451/https://lingpipe-blog.com/2009/10/14/coding-chunkers-as-taggers-io-bio-bmewo-and-bmewo/) are also common.

In your example, `Apple MacBook` could be one entity of type `Product Name`, but could also be two, with `Apple` as `Company Name` and `MacBook` as `Product Name`. How that works depends completely on your training data.

You can create data like this by hand or visually using [brat](http://brat.nlplab.org/).